# Junit Test for a method that has byte parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, byte

I'm new to Junit test and my question is : How can I write a very good test for this method.
I want a test that can cover all the corner cases.
Thank you all.

```
public static byte myMethod(byte b1) {

    byte b2 = b1;

    if ((b1 >> 4 & 0x0F) > 0x09)
    {
        b2 = (byte) (b1 & 0x0F);
    }
    if ((b1 & 0x0F) > 0x09)
    {
        b2 = (byte) (b1 >> 4);
    }

    if ((b2 & 0x0F) > 0x09)
    {
        b2 = (byte) 0xFF;
    }
    else
    {
        b2 = (byte) ((b2 & 0x0F) + 10 * (b2 >> 4 & 0x0F));
    }
    return b2;
}
```

Comment: what is the method supposed to do?

Comment: a test should verify **expected behavior**. can you tell us, what the expected result is? otherwhise the chances are high that your question is closed as to broad.

Comment: First, it would be nice to say what your code should do. Second, by *cover all corner cases* I suppose you want the test verify that on given *interesting* inputs it returns correct output, right ? If you had a list of those (input, output) pairs, it would be easy to write a Parameterized test

Comment: @k3b : for this input : (byte) 0xBD, output is -1

Comment: @k3b : for this input : (byte) 0x2C, output is : 2

Comment: @Arthur - the question is not so much what a concrete output number for a concrete input number should be but more what the meaning of the method is. What does the input `0xBD` mean? And why must the output for that input be `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to test "all the corner cases", you need to test all the possible inputs - so, you might do that with something like this:

```
@Test
public void testByteMethod() {
    // Every possible byte.
    for (int b = Byte.MIN_VALUE; b <= Byte.MAX_VALUE; b++) {
        byte r = myMethod((byte) b);
        System.out.printf("%d = %d\n", b, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont want to do this in an actual unit test. All unit tests should test single condition, otherwise if the single test fails, how would you know which part has failed?

Comment: @Elliott: Is this supposed to be a real answer?

Comment: "I want a test that can cover all the corner cases."

Comment: @ElliottFrisch am sure the OP meant to ask for the best way to write tests, since he says he is new to junit test

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : For example if I give (byte) 0xBD to the method or other Hex numbers like this

Comment: @Arthur Okay. What is the unit of work? It takes a byte in, it returns a byte out. It doesn't have a meaningful name... so what does it do?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : for this input--->(byte) 0xBD, output is -1

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : or for this input : (byte) 0x2C, output is : 2

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : But your code just returns 0 for all byte numbers.

Comment: @Arthur No. My code just calls your code with every byte number.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write a unit test you need a *little bit* of knowledge of the implementation of the method under test and a *big deal* of knowledge about what it is supposed to do. You only gave us the first bit.

Having said that, since a test can never cover every single possible case, you would usually try to define classes of inputs for which the same type of behavior is expected, and for each class you take one or a few example inputs.

From your code you could deduce the following classes:

- Numbers for which `(b1 >> 4 & 0x0F) > 0x09`
- Numbers for which `(b1 & 0x0F) > 0x09`
- Numbers for which `(b2 & 0x0F) > 0x09`
- Numbers for which `(b2 & 0x0F) <= 0x09` (for the else part)

If those sets of numbers intersect, you may want an example for each of the intersection sets as well as the parts of the sets that do not intersect.

Each of these conditional blocks in your code will probably have a semantic meaning. You should make those meanings explicit. A good unit test does not only test the code for correctness but also document what/why something is being tested.

E.g.
    myMethod_WhenSomeSpecificCaseHoldsTrue_ShouldSpitOutThisAndThat

I am really sorry for the vague example name but I can't guess a better one without you giving us information about the *big deal* question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the test cases proposed by Arthur (thanks to him) here is what could be a junit Parameterized test (declarations omitted for simplicity)

EDIT: add placeholders for comments as suggested by chicodoro

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
/**
* Details on what the test is for
*/
public class Ess1Test {
    byte b1; // input value for myMethod
    byte b2; // corresponding output value for myMethod

    public Ess1Test(Integer input, Integer output) {
        b1 = input.byteValue();
        b2 = output.byteValue();
    }

    @Parameters
    /**
    * List of pairs [ input_value, expected_result ] for myMethod
    */
    public static List<Object[]> getParameters() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            new Object[]{0xBD, -1}, // details on what the test case represents
            new Object[]{0x2C, 2}, // another famous condition
        });
    }

    @Test
    /**
    * Test that myMethod returns correct values on the above conditions
    */
    public void testMyMethod() {
        assertEquals(b2, myMethod(b1));
    }
}
```

To add some other *corner cases*, it is enough to add them to array in `getParameters`. It is a simple solution to run same test again multiple conditions.

Comment: **Nb:** because `getParameters()` is a method, you can easily write code to generate your test data if you'd like. This is useful when there is an easy (to verify _and/or_ write) slow method to generate correct results but you are trying to generate an optimised version.

Comment: The OP asked "how can I write a *very good* test. Of course this is mainly opinion-based. And yet I suggest that a very good test does not simply consist of numbers. It should communicate. You define a matrix of numbers but no programmer that will touch the code and/or test will have a chance to find out why it is supposed to be that way. You also run into danger of executing your actual code and copy-pasting the outputs into the "expected" matrix. Nobody will ever notice since there is no human-readable explanation for the test.

Comment: I think the `@Parameters` should be used to generate numbers for *one* certain "semantic" set of expected results, and that set should be given a name. "testMyMethod" is a completely meaning-less name.

Comment: @chiccodoro For the name *testMyMethod*, is is directly derived from the original name that was `myMethod`. For the remaining, of course you are right and in real world I never write a peace of code without comments ! But the question was not very clear about *real* use cases ... Nevertheless, I edited my post to add placeholders for human readable explanations. My original post had no ambition beyond presenting Parameterized junit tests that IMHO are relevant for testing *many corner cases*.